How did Hämmerling manage to transplant nulei in Acetabularia?
In all educational sources, the method of determining the role of the nucleus in a cell by Joachim Hämmerling is clearly described, however, no method is presented which would enable the experiment's reproduction.
A part of the experiment also involves cutting up the elongated part of the cell and swapping it with other species of Acetabularia. How was it done?

I'd recommend searches including "method" like "Acetabularia grafting method". That led me to this book chapter:
Keck, K. (1964). Culturing and experimental manipulation of Acetabularia. In Methods in Cell Biology (Vol. 1, pp. 189-213). Academic Press.
Some quotes:

DeWecker iridectomy scissors with short, pointed blades are recommended for cutting the cell into various segments. During the grafting
operations, the components are held and manipulated with fine forceps
(Watchmaker’s Forceps)

So, to cut up the cells you hold them with a fine tweezer and snip them with scissors.

A cytoplasmic surface exposed by a cut will retain its tendency for
fusion when brought in contact with similarly exposed cytoplasm of
another cell section. In practice, the components are joined by inserting
the cut end of the narrower stalk into the opening of a slightly wider stalk.
...
The joining of two stalk ends can be greatly facilitated by making
the plane of the cut slightly oblique to the long axis of the cell.
...
During the grafting operation the partners
should be gently pushed in place; parts may also be guided by holding
them in the gap above closed tips of forceps. Any hard pinching with
forceps will cause a local fragmentation of the cytoplasm.

To graft them together you physically manipulate the cut ends and push them together. They recommend cutting "on the bias" to make it easier. The process seems a bit finnicky and requires gentle handling. It seems like failure is fairly common, success comes by attempting many grafts and keeping the ones that work.
As you can see, it's conceptually quite simple which is likely why there isn't much of a detailed description in the other sources you've read. The methodology is mostly in the maintenance of cultures of these cells and in fine surgical manipulation skills.

Thank You, that is very imformative, however, by grafting we can only conclude that something in the rhizoid is responsible for the cap's colour and shape. As far as I am aware, one of the experiment's steps involved the removal and transplant of the nucleus, which was the denfinite proof that nuclei are responsible for morphology, not the entire rhizoid.

@Inva7 Nope, just the rhizoid containing the nucleus versus other parts of the cell.
